# I don't know the difference between to infinitive and gerund in terms of nuance

Tags: meaning, infinitive-vs-gerund

1. I like to sing.
2. I like singing.

I don't know the difference in meaning.
please tell me the difference. I am talking about nuance.

Answer (score 4):

I assume here your intended meaning is that when *you* sing, you enjoy it, and you're not talking about enjoying the sound of *other people* singing.

A short answer is that the two are always interchangeable with no significant difference in meaning, so as a language learner, you cannot choose incorrectly.

But indeed, there is a difference. With "to sing" the focus is more on *the moment* of you singing, whereas with "singing" the focus is more on *the general concept* of you singing.

For example, if I sing in a choir, and I feel good while I'm singing or after singing, and I'm thinking about those moments, then I'm *somewhat* more likely to say, "I like to sing in a choir."

But if I'm not thinking about particular instances of singing, but want to state that it's an activity that I feel good about doing in general, I'd be *somewhat* more likely to say, "I like singing in a choir".

In these examples below, I give what I believe is the *somewhat* more likely usage, but saying it the other way around is also correct and 100% natural for native speakers:

> *I like **to sing** when I drive long distances.*

> *I like **singing** because it relaxes me.*

> *What are you hobbies?*
> *I like **singing***.

> *What do you do in your spare time?*
> *I like **to sing***.

The two are so similar, that if someone asked you a question with one version, you could answer with the other:

> *Why do you like **to sing**?*
> *I like **singing** because it relaxes me.*

The difference is so subtle that I don't think I've ever seen the two differentiated in any ESL materials in my 17 years of teaching. I have no doubt Socioinguists have conducted many studies about this difference, but you'd have to search up academic papers to see what they say.

Comment: thank you very much for you kind explanation~ it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I’m not entirely sure about what you mean by “nuance”. I’ll describe the major difference in meaning.

The first sentence implies that “I” is the agent of “to sing”. In the second sentence, “singing” doesn’t have an agent; perhaps the speaker enjoys his or her own singing, but perhaps he or she enjoys the singing of other people, the idea of singing, etc.

Comment: +1 Yes. Grammatically, in your final interpretation of 2. "singing" is strictly speaking  ambiguous between a noun and a verb. In the _verb_ interpretation it has the same meaning as 1. ("I like singing = I like to sing") .

Comment: It's not noun-vs-verb that's ambiguous (it's a noun); it's *which* singing the subject likes.

Comment: thank you very much~

Comment: While it's technically ambiguous, unless the context makes it clear they're talking about other people singing (which suggests the speaker actually enjoys listening), the default interpretation is that they mean themselves.

Comment: @chepner I disagree. In "I like singing", "singing" may well be a verb. In fact, I'd say that verb is the more salient interpretation, in which case it would have the same structure and meaning as the OP's ex 1.